# Fullpage picture in two column layout

Tags: latex

I'd like to insert a picture (figure) into a document which is using a two-column layout. However, I want it to take one whole page and not be centered on one of the columns. Currently if I add a `[p]` modifier to the figure, the whole image lands on the last page, instead in the middle of the document.

How can I force one page to switch back to a single-column layout and insert a single big picture there?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

`\usepackage{multicol}` in your preamble.

Then

```
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

blah blah blah text

\end{multicols}

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{arc}
\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}

blah blah blah text

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

This is ugly, and dirty. and you will need to fiddle with where you figure is in order to get the text balanced, but it is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: This is NOT recommended. It breaks the WHOLE FLOW of the columns and restarts after the figure completely new with arranging columns. Meaning the text is completely out of flow

Comment: Is your problem the same as OP? Can you do something other than complain? Maybe a minimal working example??

Comment: This solution is not recommended if a template has already been provided. Otherwise, for the personal template, it works fine.

Answer (score 104):

Use the `figure*` environment. So instead of

```
\begin{figure}[ht] % I typically use ht
\centering
...
\end{figure}
```

you should use

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
...
\end{figure*}
```

This also works for tables (i.e. `table*`).
Consider [this link](https://texblog.org/2012/07/30/single-column-figuretable-in-a-two-multi-column-environment/) for more information

Comment: The problem with this approach is that my columns are not balanced anymore on the last page if I use `figure*`. Not sure why it has any connection, but still :/

Comment: I'm affraid of taht this workd only as `\begin{figure*}` or `\begin{figure*}[t]` initiation command. `[p]`,`[h]` and `[b]` parameters forced image to be set with correct dimensions but on last page.

Comment: For me, [t] and [p] worked as expected: [t] put it at the top of the page, and [p] put it on a new page not at the end of the document. Agreed that [h] and [b] do not work with this method.

Not sure what the issue is with unbalanced columns, viraptor. Are the column widths are different?

Comment: Wow, smack me upside the head, viraptor. I understand what you mean by unbalanced now - length. Anywho, it seems to work for me. I'm using `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` with `\usepackage{balance}` in my preamble, then a `\balance` command just before I start my text for that section. Using the `[t]` for the figure, I get what I expect: figure at the top of a page in my text, and balanced-length columns on the last page.

Comment: Can't have `h` for a wide float, and `b` will only work if the figure is small enough (use `!` to override this, though).

Answer (score 14):

It is not elegant, but with `float` package loaded you can use:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\onecolumn\includegraphics{arc}
\end{figure}
\twocolumn
```

But you have to place this piece of code to exact locetion in source code. Otherwise you'll get pagebreak anywhere in twocolumned page, then page with image image.

Comment: You saved my life man. Searched for that for hours!! Multicols is not working properly! The problem with figure* is, that it always forces the picture to a new page! Screw latex

Comment: This, plus @MCeee's answer above about using `multicol` package is the best solution

Answer (score 2):

To supplement @Crowley's answer, to avoid pagebreak after implementation.
Instead of using ***\twocolumn***, use this package instead ***\usepackage{multicol}***.
Then,

```
  \begin{multicols}{2}
   \section Write or place anything you want
    \end{multicols}
```

This works for me!

Comment: This is the same answers as provided by user:136407

Answer (score 0):

in order to insert a figure in one column style while , the text before and after the figure must remain in twocolumn style you can use the strip command provided by the cuted package

```
\usepackage{cuted}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX % text before the figure
\begin{strip}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ Figure name} 
  \captionof{figure}{Your caption here}
  \label{fig:yourlabel}
\end{strip}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX %text after page
```